# Use string variable as key in nested json in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a JSON object, `data`, I need to modify.

Right now, I am modifying the object as follows:

```
data['Foo']['Bar'] = 'ExampleString'
```

Is it possible to use a string variable to do the indexing?

```
s = 'Foo/Bar'
data[s.split('/')] = 'ExampleString'
```

The above code does not work. 
How can I achieve the behavior I am after?

---

**NB** : I am looking for a solution which supports arbitrary number of key "levels", for instance the string variable may be `Foo/Bar/Baz`, or `Foo/Bar/Baz/Foo/Bar`, which would correspond to `data['Foo']['Bar']['Baz']` and `data['Foo']['Bar']['Baz']['Foo']['Bar']`.

Comment: Yes, you can do `x = s.split('/');data[x[0]][x[1]]`?

Comment: @shaikmoeed Yes, but what if the number of elements is variable? E.g. `Foo/Bar/Baz`

Comment: does your string get a bit complex? I mean like 'Foo/Bar/inner/first/almost/here'?

Comment: @Ramesh Yes, the solution should supported arbitrary number of fields

Comment: Then, you should go with a loop until you reach the last element. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @shaikmoeed Well, I wonder whether there is a more Pythonic solution than a loop. Feel free to post it as an answer though.

Comment: Don't know how pythonic you feel this. By taking benifit of `exec`, I would think like `path='Foo/Bar/Baz/Foo/Bar';exec('data[' + ']['.join(path.split('/')) + ']')` (WIthout using loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing completely the data class you want to use, this might be easisest:

```
def jsonSetPath(jobj, path, item): 
    prev = None 
    y = jobj
    for x in path.split('/'):
        prev = y
        y = y[x]
    prev[x] = item
```

A wrapper Python to descend iteratively into the object. Then you can use

```
jsonSetPath(data, 'foo/obj', 3)
```

normally. You can add this functionality to your dictionary by inheriting `dict`  if you prefer:

```
class JsonDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, path):
        # We only accept strings in this dictionary
        y = self
        for x in path.split('/'):
            y = dict.get(y, x)
        return y

    def __setitem__(self, path, item):
        # We only accept strings in this dictionary
        y = self
        prev = None
        for x in path.split('/'):
            prev = y
            y = dict.get(y, x)
        prev[x] = item
```

note using `UserDict` from `collections` may be advised, but seems to much of a hassle without converting all the inner dictionaries to user dictionaries. Now you wrap your data (`data = JsonDict(data)`) and use it as you wanted. If you want to use non-strings as your keys, you need to handle that (though I am not sure that makes sense in this specific dictionary implementation).

Note only the "outer" dictionary is your custom dictionary. If the use case is more advanced you would need to convert all the inner ones as well, and then you might as well use `UserDictionary`.

Comment: Subclassing `UserDict` is an interesting idea. Then this behavior can be baked into `__getitem__` so no special method is needed

Comment: @DeepSpace I am writing that asws :)

Comment: BTW, `jsonGetPath` will not work. You have to verify that you return the dict, otherwise you will return the value. ie you should only do `y = y[x]` if `y[x]` is a dict

Comment: @DeepSpace I don't care which I return. Why should I? If  path to a value is given, it's on the caller, isn't it?

Comment: If you consider `data` to be `{'Foo': {'Bar': {'Baz': None}}}`, how would you use `jsonGetPath` to change `None` to `1`?

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

A very naive solution to get you going in the correct direction.

You need to add error handling, for example what happens if somewhere a long the path a key is missing? You can either bail out or add a new dict on the fly.

```
def update(path, d, value):
    for nested_key in path.split('/'):
        temp = d[nested_key]
        if isinstance(temp, dict):
            d = d[nested_key]
    d[nested_key] = value

one_level_path = 'Foo/Bar'
one_level_dict = {'Foo': {'Bar': None}}

print(one_level_dict)
update(one_level_path, one_level_dict, 1)
print(one_level_dict)

two_level_path = 'Foo/Bar/Baz'
two_level_dict = {'Foo': {'Bar': {'Baz': None}}}

print(two_level_dict)
update(two_level_path, two_level_dict, 1)
print(two_level_dict)
```

Outputs

```
{'Foo': {'Bar': None}}
{'Foo': {'Bar': 1}}
{'Foo': {'Bar': {'Baz': None}}}
{'Foo': {'Bar': {'Baz': 1}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I decided to go with `jsonSetPath` from @kabanus as it is slightly more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Using **recursion**:

```
x = {'foo': {'in':{'inner':9}}}
path = "foo/in/inner";

def setVal(obj,pathList,val):
    if len(pathList) == 1:
        obj[pathList[0]] = val
    else:
     return setVal(obj[pathList[0]],pathList[1:],val)

print(x)
setVal(x,path.split('/'),10)
print(x)
```